# Changing input fields in Yii2 depending on a value inputted in previous input field

Tags: forms, yii2

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'FEETYPE')
  ->dropDownList(['F' => 'Fixed', 'P' => 'Percentage','R' => 'Range'],['prompt' => 'Select...'], '')
  ->label('Fee Type'); ?>
```

if a user chooses Range I display a different input for the accommodating different rates. If they choose percentage I display an input field that accommodates percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options using JS when the user trigger the change event of the previus input:

1 - Destroy the next input and create again using the same plugin. (Yii2 plugins is all based on jquery plugins)

2 - Much more simple: just write the two options that you want to use, but show only one. Just use some validation that do "hide/show" jquery events.